# pfSense allow ping only from 1 IP address

Tags: firewall, ping, pfsense, rules

We are a dutch company with an office in the USA.
This office has an pfSense firewall device with the `182.12.12.12` IP address .

In the Netherlands' office we have an IP address like this: `100.12.10.12`

Is there a way that we can set up a rule in pfSense that we (in the Netherlands) could `ping 182.12.12.12` every 5 minutes (we already have a program for that) but just from the Netherlands' office so I can't ping the USA office let's say from my home.

If so, where can I set that up in pfSense?

Answer (score 1):

`ping` uses `ICMP` protocol. So basically you need to add/edit a rule in your `pfSense` firewall to allow `ICMP echo requests` if the IP address is `100.12.10.12`.

Go to `Firewall > Rules` and add a new rule which should have above criteria.

`Action` > `Pass`,
`Interface` > `WAN`,
`Protocol` > `ICMP`,
`Type` > `Echo request`,
`Source` > `100.12.10.12`,
`Description` > `Add description`

Then click `Save`

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Login to pfSense
Open Firewall > Rules.

Click [+] to add a new rule.

Change Interface to WAN.
Change Protocol to ICMP.
Change ICMP type to Echo request.
Input a description

On the source address please type **100.12.10.12/255.255.255.255**
Click Save.

[image]

Printscreen/step took [there](https://www.sxl.net/how-to-allow-ping-on-pfsense-firewall/)